# Determining component design age

Tags: component-selection

Is there a way to see when a component was designed without opening every datasheet?

I look at some TI LED driver parts first released 2007, revised 2016. Is that datasheet or component?

Does it matter? Are new technologies much different?

Answer (score 1):

It is datasheet revision date. If the component is updated, it gets a new name (or new letter(s) and/or number(s) added to the end of its name).  Electronics manufacturers are very picky about qualification processes and in-line revision of a component without clear markings of version are a no-no.

The datasheet changes could be as simple as an updated logo, address, clarification on package drawings or additional graphs/charts or clarifying some operating limits that were not previously measured or specified.